# Clicked linked withing iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

If I have a website loaded inside an iFrame, like this:

```
$("#myIframe").attr("src",url);
```

...is it possible to capture a URL of a new page when a user clicks a link withing that site?

Comment: Looks lie this has been answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472550/detect-click-inside-iframe

Comment: are you trying to load external url in iframe?

Answer (score 2):

You can attach to the onLoad Event

```
<iframe src="/test.html" onLoad="alert(this.contentWindow.location);"></iframe>
```

or

```
$('#myIframe').load(function() {
  alert("the iframe has been loaded, pull the src");
});
```

Working Sample per [Muthu Kumaran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615746/muthu-kumaran): 
http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/DuRTR/

Comment: will that event fire every time the user clicks a link inside the iframe?

Comment: @GungFoo Isn't that what he wanted, when the URL changes by someone clicking a link?

Comment: It's supported by Firfox, IE and Chrome.

Comment: @Gung Foo - Click on any link inside the iFrame and alert will appear.

Comment: I can see the alert the in FF 15 and Chrome with a text `"the iframe has been loaded, pull the src"`

Comment: Yes, it triggers the alert, but I'm not able to capture the new URL... I've tried newUrl = $("#myIframe").attr("src"); Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the content of an iframe from the page containing it since that would allow you to do alot of evil stuff like steal session cookies, make the user click stuff he didn't want to on another site, etc..

Glennulars answer will apparently work tho. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if events bubble up to the iframe, but you could try:

```
$("iframe").click(function(e){
  console.log('something was clicked');
});
```