# Deteck click into iframe in html

Tags: javascript, iframe

How to know when click into **iframe** in html? because i want to close the `dropdown` component when click into **iframe**.

I searched by google, there is a solution using `window.blur`, but this method isn't standard.

Any helps are appreciate, thanks!

Comment: Sample code you have worked upon ?

Comment: is it same domain? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472550/detect-click-inside-iframe

Comment: @gurvinder372 not same domain, the iframe content provide by third-party

Comment: @JiteshYadav i write a example http://embed.plnkr.co/DpgMF1P90dHnQPupU0Iy/

Comment: @huang.xinghui I have added the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with Javascript. The following question covers some methods on how you might implement an OnClick() method for iframes:
[Adding click event handler to iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452502/adding-click-event-handler-to-iframe)

From there, you could probably have the function go ahead and close the dropdown.

Without knowing more about your code, we can only really suggest general solutions.

Comment: yes, but the iframe content is not in the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way to get a click on iframe in javascript. But there is way around for it.
What we can instead do is track if the user hovers over the iframe and using $(window).blur() we can know if the focus has shifted from current window i.e. the webpage to iframe embedded. Focus shift will mean that user has clicked inside the iframe. Once we capture $(window).blur(), we can toggle dropdown state.

```
var iframeHover;
$('iframe').hover(function() {
  iframeHover = true;
}, function() {
  iframeHover = false;
});
$(window).blur(function() {
  if (iframeHover)
    $("#dLabel").dropdown('toggle');
});
```

Working Plnkr is: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/StfC2MEG707Gvw3LPSVU?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does `window.blur` this method is standard?

Comment: @huang.xinghui I guess its a standard method like others. Refer reference in jquery docs https://api.jquery.com/blur/