# Detect mouse over iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'd like call a function every time a user drags their mouse over an iframe (which points to a different domain). Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you already tried setting a `mouseover` event on the actual `iframe` and it didn't work. If so, you can try wrapping the `iframe` inside a `div` and set the `mouseover` event on that `div`. This **has** to work. In the worst case scenario make the `div` a little big bigger (1-2px padding) than your iframe.

Comment: I am using this technique to change the color of a text. It works fine on Firefox but on IE when the mouse is over the iFrame it considers the hover over the div is over and the text returns to the original colors. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Load a file into the iframe set the mouseover event on that file.