# Detecting Click Inside IFrame Using Invisible div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe

I went through this post.
[Detect Click into Iframe using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript)

But still, I see people have done similar stuff. Please tell me how do I do this.

One developer told me:

> You could put a transparent DIV on top of the IFRAME. You size that
>   DIV to the same size or bigger than the IFRAME. And with a higher
>   z-index CSS property.
>
> Then when you click on the IFRAME, the DIV receives the event.
>
> But as the world is not perfect, now you lost the ability to click
>   inside the IFRAME.

But I am not so good with div's and looking to learn how to do this. 
Thanks

P.S. It is about Cross Domain or Alien Domain Iframing.

Comment: Edited as per your advice. Thanks

Comment: No hijack, I am want to make a submit form work. As i don't have access to it. I am taking this route. I think Question here are asked for programming help and not about hijacks and scams? Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking here:

### *[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8cVD/)*

```
// PLACE OVERLAY OVER EACH IFRAME
var W=0, H=0, X=0, Y=0;
$(".iframe").each(function(i,el){
   W = $(el).width();
   H = $(el).height();
   X = $(el).position().left;
   Y = $(el).position().top;
   $(this).after('<div class="overlay" />');
    $(this).next('.overlay').css({
        width: W,
        height: H,
        left: X,
        top: Y        
    });
});

// TRACK MOUSE POSITIONS (the overlay will prevent clicks on iframe page)
var mx = 0, my = 0;
$('.overlay').on('mousemove click',function(e){
    mx = e.clientX - $(this).position().left;
    my = e.clientY - $(this).position().top;

    if(e.type==='click'){
        alert('clicked at: X='+mx+' Y='+my)
    }        
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate it. This question was asked rather 20 times if i remember with no perfect solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there possibility of transferring click to iframe at same coordinates?

Comment: You can't communicate with the (cross domain) iframe in any way, so no, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I think a transparent div will not work, because it will catch all click events, and not spread it down to the iframe.

So the only workaround I know to track click on iframes is using the blur event.
You can use the [iframeTracker jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/finalclap/iframeTracker-jquery) to do this easily :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.iframe_wrap iframe').iframeTracker({
        blurCallback: function(){
            // Do something when iframe is clicked (like firing an XHR request)
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Jquery's .live method.

It can attach an event handler to a selector now and in the future, such as when content is loaded into  a div.

http://api.jquery.com/live/