# Cannot re-open the drop-down list by one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a webpage made by `angularjs` and `bootstrap`, but not `ui-bootstrap`.

There is a `drop-down list` and an `iframe`. The problem is that when the drop-down list is open, clicking on the iframe will not automatically close the drop-down list.

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26586016/702977) and added the follows:

```
$(window).on('blur',function() { $('.dropdown-toggle').parent().removeClass('open'); } );
```

Now, clicking on the iframe does close the drop-down list. However, just after closing, clicking on the drop-down button will NOT re-open the list; we have to click on somewhere else than the iframe or click on the drop-down button once, then clicking again on the drop-down button opens the list.

Sorry that I cannot reproduce the problem in a playground, but it seems a common problem that "only the second click opens a drop-down list". I tried to remove `data-toggle="dropdown"`, but it did not help.

Does anyone know what I could try to fix the problem?

Comment: It might be because you need to the outer page focus before touch the dropdown again. If I am understanding the problem correctly. But an idea to try is wrapping the dropdown in an ng-if and when clicking the iframe toggle the if statement off then on this will re-render the dropdown to its natural state.

Comment: I agree that "you need to the outer page focus before touch the dropdown again", because even though we click on the iframe area many times, we have to click on somewhere else before clicking on the drop-down button to re-open it. However, I don't understand what you say about `ng-if`...

Comment: forget about the ng-if i don't think it will help. More of an alternative to using jqlite

Comment: I don't know `jqlite`, could you propose an answer?

Comment: @SoftTimur can you provide more code? because [it works in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teleginzhenya/f2ezha8m/2/)

Comment: The problem is that, when I try it on a playground, even my initial code does not have any problem...

Comment: Hi @SoftTimur can you try this `$(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle')).parent().removeClass("open")` a bit odd but may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it...

Before, I used the following, and did NOT use `bootstrap.js`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>.
```

To avoid the problem mentioned in this question, I need to use:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

Note that, `bootstrap.js` is absolutely needed, and `0.11.0` is not enough for `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`.

(* By the way, I had previously a bug (unfortunately I don't remember clearly), which was due to a not higher enough version `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`. Really need to keep in mind that `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` may be the issue when you meet a tricky js bug. *)

Comment: And this is the first sentence: I have a webpage made by angularjs and bootstrap, but not ui-bootstrap. I also wonder how your code could work on a playground.

Answer (score 0):

you can try a more "bootstrap" solution with

```
$(window).on('blur',function() { 
  if($('.dropdown-toggle').parent().hasClass('open')){
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");
  }
});
```

this will close the element if openned and let the dropdown as closed for the next click to fire the open.

Comment: With this code, when I click on the iframe, the drop-down list will not close automatically...