# Bootstrap pagination does not work with angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

Because of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43568412/702977), I need to use a high version of `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`. However, I realise that this disabled `bootstrap pagination`, which works with a lower version of `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`.

For example, [this pagination works](http://plnkr.co/edit/J2DzS6YHvu1LRKSEvRLv?p=preview) with `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`, whereas `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` [does not work](http://plnkr.co/edit/wPwBgatEivCvnqun8Z93?p=preview).

Does anyone know what I could do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0UTX9pndmpSB5onw8r7Z?p=preview) with:

```
<ul uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></ul>
```

instead of:

```
<pagination total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
```