# How to monitor iframe clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website called A i want to display another website called myFrame through A using iframe  i want to count all the clicks in myFrame and want to display in my website A.myFrame site is in different domain.I did the following code but its not working.
i can add any javascript code in myFrame website

```
<html>
<body>
Count: <span id="clicks">0</span>
<iframe id="myframe" src="http://www.myFrame.com" class="restricted" height="400px;" width="400px;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">     
</iframe>
</body>
</html>

<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
    var clicks = 0;
    $('#myframe').contents().find('a').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        clicks++;
        $('#clicks').html(clicks);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: try firing events in the `top` window

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226448/detecting-click-inside-iframe-using-invisible-div otherwise it's impossible

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible. [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents you from monitoring/accessing anything in another domain.