# Show div after specific amount of clicks in/on an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am displaying an iframe with an external URL on my website that covers the whole screen. (100% width and 100% height)

Now I came to wonder if there was still a way to register clicks with jquery/javascript even though it's an external URL being displayed.

I don't care on what region of the screen is clicked, all I care about is registering that there is a click.

The iframe still needs to be accessible, so I cannot overlay a div, since that will make the iframe useless. At least this is from my last experience.

This is a mobile website that I am talking about by the way, maybe that changes anything.

In desperate need of help! Be my savior in this quest :)

Comment: I think this answers your question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226448/detecting-click-inside-iframe-using-invisible-div?rq=1

Comment: create a click counter and if counter == specific amount than show div,

Comment: I do not think there is a possibility of doing this without an overlay `div`