# Detect a click on video

Tags: javascript, jquery

I embeded a video from `youtube` . My code is :

```
 <div id="video"><iframe width="100%" height="100%" 
   src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Vv2RRaC9dC8?wmode=transparent" 
   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

There is an `onclick` event attached with `div#video`. But i can`t able to fire it because of this video. When i click over it, the video starts playing.How can i detect the click event?

Comment: Have you tried passing the event object and using `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect Click into Iframe using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript)

Comment: Because the iframe is from a 3rd party site, the Same Origin Policy prevents you from scripting the Iframe.

Comment: You might need to initialize the YouTube API and just watch for a [player state change](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events).