# set external link to youtube iframe video

Tags: html, css, video, youtube

I am using iframe you-tube video in my website.

Sample Code:

```
<iframe width="414" height="270" src="samplecode" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If I click the youtube video it will redirect to the external page. I used the below code.

```
<a href="#"> <iframe width="414" height="270" src="samplecode" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></a>
```

I know my way is wrong. It is not working. Please confirm to do this in anyway?

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. To solve your problem you have to use javascript. For reference you can check following thread
[Detect Click into Iframe using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript)

Another Solution is

```
<div style="position:relative">
<div style="position:absolute;width:414px;height:270px" onclick='window.location.href="http://google.com"' ></div>
<iframe width="414" height="270" src="samplecode" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Here I superimposed another div overiframe (we will not set any background for it, so iframe content will be seen) which will have onclick function which will take user to desired url