# Add link to iframe

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

How do I add a link to external iframe?

```
<iframe id='abcdef' name='abcdef' src='http://externaldomain.com?id=99' framespacing='0' frameborder='no' scrolling='no' width='960' height='60'>
    <a href='http://anotherexternaldomain.com' target='_blank'>
        <img src='http://externaldomain.com?pic=99' border='0' alt='' />
    </a>
</iframe>
```

This is external ads which is put inside my website. I want to add a link to this iframe in order to track the impression and number of click

Is there any way to use with jQuery perhaps? Thank you!

Comment: you may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript

Comment: thanks Igor, i'll take a look on this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway i've thought a way to add link. I'm using an overlay div with absolute position to cover the iframe entirely so the iframe is behind the div. Thanks anyone who has helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The `iframe`'s content is whatever its `src` tells it. You might be able to proxy the ad and track the clicks, but usually ad providers will track clicks for you.

Side-note:

> with jQuery perhaps?

There is nothing jQuery can do that cannot be done in plain JavaScript. If JS can't do it, neither can jQuery.

Comment: But my company wants to track the clicks also. Is there anyway perhaps?

Comment: Nope. Just because your company wants it doesn't mean it's possible.