# GWT hide a frame

Tags: java, gwt, hide, frame

I have a frame panel

```
Frame frameExample = new Frame();
```

I need to hide the frame when I click on it, I know the method `setvisible`

```
frameExample.setVisible(false);
```

But how can add `onclick` handler on frame in gwt?

Answer (score 0):

To add handler for known DOM events on Frame you should use addDomHandler api. Frame extends from Widget and widget has addDomHandler api.

Also from the addDomHandler java doc

```
 /**
   * Adds a native event handler to the widget and sinks the corresponding
   * native event. If you do not want to sink the native event, use the generic
   * addHandler method instead.
   */
```

However i am not sure whether Click event is supported by Frame. A quick stackoveflow search for similar javascript problem gives [Detect Click into Iframe using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript).

Comment: The GWT [Frame](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html) class wraps **`<iframe>`** and your warning above refers to the `<frame>` element.