# iFrame from Youtube. Get click event with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, post, youtube

I have a list of 8 videos from youtube in my app (thumbnails).
I need to detect the click event in one of those videos, and them, via `AJAX` (`$.post()`) load the video in the same `<div>`.
So, I have a problem... I can't detect the click event in the `iFrame`. And for my project (accessibility) I can't use plain images as the ones youtube uses in the thumbnails, without the play button! (this project is for mentally disabled kids to use youtube and a lot of rules must be followed!)

I use the jQuery framework!
Any solutions?

Comment: can you put some code here?

Comment: I use the iframe from youtube. 
Ex:
`code` <iframe id="youtubeFrame" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/".$videoCod."\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen ></iframe> `code`
The onClick event doesn't work. When I try $("#youtubeFrame").click(...) does not work. 
I have every iFrame inside one div, but i can't detect the click event in it too!
(sorry my english! I'm portuguese!)

Comment: Edit your question instead of commenting it.

Comment: I would say this is not going to be very easy / precise.

If you had control over the iframe content you could use messaging but being a youtube clip you wont have that.

That being said a quick search found this question which seems very similar and does have a number of "working" solutions.

Perhaps one will be acceptable for your situation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks Maurice Butler, I find the solution in that link!

Comment: Can you use PrettyPhoto? http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/