# Knowing when a facebook buttons is clicked, in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, iframe

So on my page I am embedding Facebook like so:

Here is the code that it outputs,

```
<div class="facebook">          
 <div id="fb-root" class=" fb_reset">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px;"><div>

  <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" name="fb_xdm_frame_http" allowtransparency="true" id="fb_xdm_frame_http" aria-hidden="true" title="Facebook Cross Domain Communication Frame" tab-index="-1" style="border: medium none;" src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=24#channel=f194f0214c1b73&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fqantascu.dev.com&amp;channel_path=%2Fabout.html%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Df1bc3676c1f570e%26"></iframe>    

  <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" name="fb_xdm_frame_https" allowtransparency="true" id="fb_xdm_frame_https" aria-hidden="true" title="Facebook Cross Domain Communication Frame" tab-index="-1" style="border: medium none;" src="https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=24#channel=f194f0214c1b73&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fqantascu.dev.com&amp;channel_path=%2Fabout.html%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Df1bc3676c1f570e%26"></iframe>

  </div>
 </div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px;"><div></div></div></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <fb:like colorscheme="light" action="recommend" show_faces="false" width="200" layout="button_count" send="true" href="http://qantascu.dev.com/about.html" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" class="fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget"><span style="height: 20px; width: 166px;">
<iframe scrolling="no" id="f21dc10b55b8de4" name="f14dd27ab0fc5" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 20px; width: 166px;" title="Like this content on Facebook." class="fb_ltr" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=&amp;locale=en_US&amp;sdk=joey&amp;channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D24%23cb%3Df314d5a8f7b12c6%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fqantascu.dev.com%252Ff194f0214c1b73%26domain%3Dqantascu.dev.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fqantascu.dev.com%2Fabout.html&amp;node_type=link&amp;width=200&amp;layout=button_count&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=recommend&amp;show_faces=false&amp;send=true&amp;extended_social_context=false"></iframe></span></fb:like></div>
```

I want to be able to know when someone has clicked on a button, this was the code I tried

```
jQuery(".facebook iframe").on("click", function(e){
  alert("clicked");        
});
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very easy way to achieve what you want. Facebook [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/) offers `FB.Event.subscribe` which you can use to Attach an handler to an event and invoke your callback when the event fires. Quoting example from [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) that would callback when user likes something

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
  function(response) {
    alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
  }
);
```

Quoting from the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) information about `edge.create` used here

> **edge.create** - fired when the user likes something (fb:like). The response parameter to the callback function contains the URL that was liked:
>   "http://www.example.com/article1.php"