# iframe height change if clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I need to change the height of an iframe when clicked. The iframe is created with this code:

```
var box = document.createElement('iframe');
box.id = "statasa";
box.setAttribute('onclick', 'getmap()');
box.src = 'http://www.mysite.com/map.php';
box.frameBorder = 1;
box.style.border = 1;
box.style.overflow = 'hidden';
box.style.cursor = 'pointer';
box.style.width = '300px';
box.style.height =  '720px';
box.style.position = 'absolute';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(box);
```

And this is the function:

```
function getmap() {
    d = document.getElementById('statasa');
    d.style.width="150px";
    d.style.height="150px";
}
```

Where is the error? Are there simpler methods?

Comment: You cannot click an "iframe" and reduce its width and height because...it will effect its child elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect a click event in an iframe.  See [Detect Click into Iframe using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript).

---

As for the second part of the question, one way to simplify is instead of:

```
box.setAttribute('onclick', 'getmap()');
```

use:

```
box.onclick = getmap();
```

Comment: is working but only if i click the iframe border