# Disable form button until user clicks anywhere in an iframe

Tags: jquery, button, iframe

I am working on a site for a client and he has a form button that when clicked will take the user to a page offering a freebie. He wants the button to be disabled until the user has clicked on an ad that is served up in an iframe.

Is something like this even possible?

I have set up a jsFiddle to show what I've done so far: http://jsfiddle.net/dL7JT/

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#adslot > a').click(function() {
        $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<iframe id="adslot" style="border: 0; width: 180px; height: 150px;" src="http://coinurl.com/get.php?id=19647" height="240" width="320" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<form>
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I'm guessing it's the iFrame that is tripping me up.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `security reasons`, Web browsers won't let you access an `iframe`'s content(It is possible only if the `iframe` resides in the `same domain` as the `parent` page).U can perform this if its in the same domain.You could check for yourself in the below link mate... :)

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jaatA/

Comment: Dang...I'll have to figure something else out then. Thanks for clarifying for me!