# jQuery getting focus back to main window after click in iframe

Tags: jquery, facebook, iframe

I'm using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8101458/3197255) to count clicks (on e.g facebook, twitter, ect. iframes).

> Basically what it does is keep track of what iFrame people are hovering. Then if the window blurs that most likely means the user clicked the iframe banner.

If I click on another element inside the iframe, after I already clicked one, it won't count. I need to click somwhere on the website and back on the iframe to get click counted.

(e.g I click on facebook button, facebook window pops up, my click is counted. I close pop-up window, click on twitter button, my click is not counted unless I click somewhere on the page and the twitter button again)

I need to set focus back to main window somehow.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var overiFrame = -1;
        jQuery('iframe#fb').hover(function() {
        overiFrame = jQuery(this).closest();
    }, function() {
        overiFrame = -1
    });
    jQuery(window).blur(function() {
        if(overiFrame != -1 ){
           //do something
    });
```

Comment: What is the actual metric which you are trying to record in Google Analytics? Counting clicks on the iframe sounds a bit strange to me. Are you trying to work out who canceled a Facebook / Twitter share or something?

Comment: I want to track social engagement as an event in Google Analytics. I want to count clicks on facebook, twitter etc. inside iframe.

The website iframes running on other domains. It is impossible to access information inside. 

This solution solves a part of the problem and I can count every click in the iframe (without knowing which button was clicked, at least that, but I want to make it a little bit better).

Comment: Are you using a Facebook like button or share button? The FB sdk provides events for when a like button is clicked (event is triggered in parent page by the like button iframe- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/). Twitter's button also has events - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events

Comment: @madebydavid I would like to collect information with Google Analytics about any clicks on social sharing bar. Here is [sharebar example](http://www.recipe.com/revelatory-caramel-cake/) it differs between websites. Here we have facebook, pinit, google plus. It's tricky because of iframes runned on other domains as in this example.

Comment: I think I understand what you are doing - you should be able to call the Google Analytics _trackEvent function in the callback events for the FB like button or Twitter button. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: @madebydavid you are right. But I have access only to Google tag manager and have no rights to change content. 

I've changed code in my post to abstract from Google Analytics.