# Click over an iFrame by clicking dynamically on certain coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, coordinates

I am trying to click over an iframe, where there is a button, by clicking dynamically on certain coordinates. I created a button which dinamically clicks on the coordinates where that button is located, but it does not work.

In this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7gxwgnw/) sample I have the button clicks on the coordinate of x=30px and y=30px of the document where the bing logo is located, but when I click on the button, the Bing logo in iframe does not trigger.

```
<div class="button">Click Here</div>
<iframe src="https://www.bing.com/images" width="200" height="70"></iframe>



<script>
          function clicktransfer(x, y) {
                jQuery(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();
            }

            $( ".gray" ).click(function() {
            clicktransfer(30, 30);
            });
</script>
```

> [**Click here for JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p7gxwgnw/)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Similar question: [How to detect a click inside of an iframe (cross-domain)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337304/how-to-detect-a-click-inside-of-an-iframe-cross-domain-aka-prevent-click-frau)

Comment: Please explain what part I am doing wrong, I read this (cross-domain) post but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Your script has accessed to the main document. The document in the iframe is a separate document with its own DOM structure.
You may access it like this:

```
var doc = $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document;
```

But with a cross-domain restriction. In other words, you CAN NOT access a document in the iframe that has a different origin.

Comment: Is there any workaround? Not to access the other document, but at least to change the click the way to make it affect whatever is behind it, iframe or anything...

Comment: You can put a proxy-script at your web-server side. As example, the URL in iframe becomes like this:
'/proxy.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2Fimages'.
So, the browser sees the same domain in the URL, and allows access to the document under iframe.
But this method has a drawback: all relative urls in a foreign document will be broken. And absolute urls will not use your proxy.

Comment: You may workaround it by modifying urls in all <a> and <form> elements in a document (by proxy script, or by javascript on the main page). But I have no idea, how to intercept javascript calls like document.location change and window.open without a deep code analyzing.