# Tracking Embedded Spotify Track Clicks

Tags: javascript, spotify

How to track clicks within a Spotify iFrame for embedded tracks? The best I've found so far is to use the solution below from this link:
[How to detect a click inside of an iframe (cross-domain)? Aka prevent click fraud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337304/how-to-detect-a-click-inside-of-an-iframe-cross-domain-aka-prevent-click-frau)

```
var clickIframe = window.setInterval(checkFocus, 100);
var i = 0;

function checkFocus() {
  if(document.activeElement == document.getElementById("element-id")) {
    alert("dick don't break");
    window.focus();
   }
}
```

This solution is not ideal because it tracks clicks within the whole frame, and sometimes fires when the user presses tab. The idea is to know when a user clicks our embedded track link, so that we can track this with FB pixel.

If there is no way to accurately track clicks on cross domain iFrames, is there a better solution within Spotify's apis to help us track player interactions?