# Selection objects and cross-origin iframes?

Tags: javascript, iframe

When a user selects text in a different-origin iframe, javascript calling window.getSelection() running in the containing document gets back a None selection object, because of cross-origin security policies.

So, programmatically, I can't tell the difference between getting back a None selection object because the user hasn't selected anything in the entire document, versus getting back a None because a user has selected something in the different-origin iframe, but it's off-limits to my code.

I'd like to be able to distinguish between the cases so I can show the user different error messages. Is this possible?

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
if ( sel && sel.type == 'None' ) {
    // Did the user not select anything in the entire document?
    // Or did the user select something in a different origin 
    // iframe that I can't see?
    // If I could tell the difference between these two cases,
    // I could show my user a much better error message
    alert('sel type = None, dunno what it means exactly, kthxbai');
}
```

Complete demo code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/t3bd6zy4/2/

Note: This needs to work with arbitrary websites, so altering the origin policies or doing something with postMessage() isn't a viable approach for me. Also, this code will run in recent Chrome browsers only.

UPDATE: I have a workaround to this problem, albeit one that will work only in Chrome extensions.

While I can't get different-origin selectedText from the DOM without altering the origin policies, the Chrome APIs will let you get selected text even if it does come from a different-origin iframe. (If you want to know more, see the samples for the contextMenus API: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.)

Using this approach means I don't need to show iframe-specific messages for empty selections. Fewer error messages for my users: much awesomeness.

Comment: I very much doubt you can. But hey, worth asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3bd6zy4/3/)):

```
var iframeClicked = false;

document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', iframe(false));

function iframe(bool) {
  return function(e) {
      iframeClicked = bool;   
      //console.log(iframeClicked);
  }
}

focus();
var listener = addEventListener('blur', function() {
  if(document.activeElement === document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]) {
      iframe(true)();
  }

  removeEventListener(listener);
});

document.getElementById('selbutton').addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  var sel = window.getSelection();

  if (!iframeClicked) {
      console.log("selection type of " + sel.type + " value is :" + sel + ":" );
  } else {
      console.log("did not get a selection object back from getSelection");
  }
});
```

The solution to check if the `iframe` was clicked can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23231136/2714730). What we're looking for is to see if the `iframe` was the last thing that was clicked (because as you know, if you select something, the next thing you click will unselect that selection... so if the `iframe` was the last thing clicked, and we click the "get selection" button, then we'll know that we tried to select something inside the `iframe`.) That was confusing.

Anyway, `iframeClicked === true` means that the last thing *before* clicking the "get selection" button that the user clicked was indeed the `iframe`. Otherwise, it was somewhere *outside* the `iframe`.

Comment: Yes, indeed, this does work! Wow, I was thinking this was really unsolvable; nicely done (and accepted)!