# How to capture all the events performed on iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, web

**NOTE** : The url of iframe is external link which is on different domain that I cannot modify.

I could get a solution in which I was able to detect only a click event .

```
var monitor = setInterval(function(){
var elem = document.activeElement;
if(elem && elem.tagName == 'IFRAME'){
    message.innerHTML = 'Clicked';
    clearInterval(monitor);
}
}, 100);
```

Also , at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript) place it has been stated that there is no way we can capture the events of an `external iFrame` . I want to capture all the events . Is it possible ?

Comment: _"Also , at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript) place it has been stated that there is no way we can capture the events of an external iFrame . I want to capture all the events . Is it possible ?"_ I think you've answered your own question here.  If you have no control over the other page, then no, it's not possible.  Imagine you put a banking site in an iframe - you'd be able to capture the keystrokes of someone logging in.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I strongly agree !

Answer (score 0):

If you own both sites/domains then use postmessage when clicking in child document, this won't work on IE8

- postmessage
  http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage
- for ie8
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511311(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have clearly stated that the url of iframe is external link which is on different domain .

Comment: domain is not a problem, if u can't control content of iframe ,  it would be. still u can use proxy+modify or other method to make as is same domain, or ajax into same document