# Iframe not working with label in form

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

**Problem**

I want to check a checkbox when an iframe is clicked. Normally I would just use an label around the input. And this works for images, text and others. But it doesn't seem to work for iframes?

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VdJ9m/140/)

**Here's my code**

```
<form>
  <label>

      <iframe src="http://yx-ads6.com/banner_show.php?section=General&amp;pub=836169&amp;format=468x60&amp;ga=g" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="468" height="60" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe

    <input type="checkbox">
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: I would prefer use an span at top to make this work like I did into http://jsfiddle.net/VdJ9m/146/
the previus one was not updated, if fixed the link.

Comment: Cheers that worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make using an element above the iframe like this:

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <label>
    <span></span>
      <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="468" height="60" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="background-color: #fff"></iframe>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </label>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
span {
  width: 468px; 
  height: 60px; 
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

here a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VdJ9m/146/) about this code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the click event is within the `iframe` not the label, so the input is not checked.

You can do this with JS. Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32138108/4556503

Comment: I'm not great at JavaScript, but how would I get it to check the checkbox after the script detects the click?