# capture iframe click event for google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have a page with several iframes that display content from external hosts. I would like to track with the help of Google Tag Manager, which iframe was clicked by a user. I found that javascript doesn't capture events for iframe. I was wondering if there is a trick that can be used to bypass the issue. I'm open to any suggestion meaning iframe can be replaced with any other container that can display external html.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23231136/4648772

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Click into Iframe using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript)

Comment: possibly see: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/iframe-cross-domain-tracking-in-google-tag-manager/