# jQuery click on iframe video (youtube)

Tags: jquery, video, iframe, click

I have an html iframe that contains just an embeded youtube video. I'm trying to perform an action when the user clicks the video/iframe but does not work. Here is code:

html:

```
<iframe id="myVideo" autoplay="true" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pyvGEnmv1E0"></iframe>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  //line in question:
  $('#myVideo').contents().find("body").click(function(){
    //perform action here
  });
});
```

On the "line in question" above, I have also tried the more simple-

```
$('#myVideo').click(function(){});
```

but that fails also.  Any help is wonderfully appreciated.

Andrew

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need click events to get through to the iFrame, you could use an overlay, and capture the click event on that.

Like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="myVideoWrapper">
    <iframe id="myVideo" autoplay="true" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pyvGEnmv1E0"></iframe>
    <div id="myVideoOverlay"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myVideoWrapper {
    position:relative;
}

#myVideoOverlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myVideoOverlay').click(function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your quick answer, unfortunately that did not solve the problem at all. The full code of your solution is here: www.samedaygrocerydelivery.net/test2.txt and implemented here: www.samedaygrocerydelivery.net/test2.php

Comment: You need to add the CSS as well - that will make the overlay div element sit on top of the iframe element.  Then you should see the click event fired.  But like I said, it will block click events going through to iframe, so it is probably not a good solution for you.  There is a trick described on the following link which may be better for you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript#answer-23231136

Comment: yeah that link you provided above worked for me. Thanks David. -Andrew