# Finding click-counter for NFP website, written in iframe

Tags: iframe, onclick, click, counter, buttonclick

I am a non-programmer working for a church. We have no tech staff. Our website is based upon a template that doesn't provide a widget for counting clicks. We'd like to add one (or preferably two) jpg image(s) with a counter(s) to track the number of times clicked, and display the cumulative total next to the jpg(s). Church members will go to the page and click each time they participate in one or both of two different church objectives.

Our web host says to do this I must find, write, or purchase 3rd party code written in iframe, to embed into one of our pages.

I googled the issue and am only finding hit counters which track visitors to a page, rather than clicks of an image. We'd prefer two different jpgs to track two different objectives, but if necessary I can change from two jpgs to one, if having two counters on the same page is a problem.

Can anyone point me to where I could get code like this either for free, or for pay, and what it would cost?

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.* Stack Overflow isn't designed for this type of question, it's for questions about writing code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of good information here. They talk about an issue with iframe receiving the click vs. you recording it. If you keep reading there is a possibility to work it. Hope this helps!

Look here: [Detect Click into Iframe using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript/23231136#23231136)