# How to track Facebook likes through Page Plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've created a Facebook 'Page plugin' using the 
javascriptSDK on this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

Everything works well, I've added an App Id and we're receiveing analytics in the developers.facebook.com/apps/ page for impressions, demographics etc.

What I want and I can't see are **how many people actually 'LIKE' my Facebook page through the button in that plugin**. Is there a way to do this within the facebook tools that I'm missing or can someone come up with another solution to the same end?

The page holding the plugin is a wordpress page and I've tried a number of wordpress plugins that didn't track those button click likes either. It's also a very difficult subject to Google.

Thanks, Ben

Comment: if you navigate to the page you're tracking, is there a way to scrape the number of likes from the page source?

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook. in that case, it would be pointless anyway. unless there is something about that in the existing insights, there is nothing you can do. there is the edge.create event, but i believe it is deprecated.

Comment: not sure about facebook side, but you can always try something like [adding a listener to that button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23231136/9041947)