# How can I track a button click from a different UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jenkins, grails

I'm sorry if this question isn't framed the way it should, I have trouble wording out my problem.

Is it possible to see which button the user clicked, if the button was on a different UI?

I have a GSP page that is displaying a Jenkins Blue Ocean to monitor a pipeline. I want to track if the user has pressed any pause or abort buttons, but because the Jenkins Blue Ocean isn't part of my page, I can't send anything to my controller.

Would there be any work arounds or methods to track something like this?

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by another UI?? if the javascript can access same window. then can create listeners else u can push in localStorage and get data

Comment: Does the Jenkins window implements a `postMessage` that you can listen for?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript