# How to make a transition from an iframe to a page in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a html page where when a button is clicked it opens an iframe page. 
In the iframe I made a button to close it, but it doesn't work. 
iframe and page are all the same site!

```
let closeBtn = document.querySelector ("# close_btn"); // The "cross" button in the iframe
closeBtn.onclick = function () {

     write.classList.add ("write-off"); // Add the class to the main HTML page
     dimming.classList.add ("write-dimming-off"); // Add the class to the main HTML page
};
```

It doesn't work either.

```
let closeBtn = document.querySelector ("# close_btn");
closeBtn.onclick = function() {

    window.parent.document.querySelector(".write").classList.add("write-off");
    window.parent.document.querySelector(".write-dimming").classList.add("write-off");
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect Click into Iframe using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript)

Comment: You cannot do it

Answer (score 0):

assign an id to your iframe, like <iframe id="Closed"...

Then you need a function to remove the iframe

```
<a href="javascript: window.parent.document.getElementById('Closed').parentNode.removeChild(window.parent.document.getElementById('Closed'))">Close</a>
```

Comment: It works yes!
But I need, when clicking the "cross" in the iframe, add classes to the boxes on the main page.
I want to do the following: 1) I need to click on a button on the home page. 2) Open the shape in the middle of the window, and darken the background. I think this is done via an iframe .. (pop up for site)