# how to get keystrokes inside frame and simultaneously copy them outside the frame?

Tags: javascript, html

Goal: listen for keystrokes sent to a form inside the iframe ( different domain ) while copying them at the same time inside an input outside the iframe

I tried different stuff based on these solutions [Detect Click into Iframe using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript), but I could not make it work. I just could not make both things happen at the same time.

Code: I had to revert to the "basic" code. If possibile, I would like to stick to pure javascript.

```
..
<input type="text" name="test" value="$here should go what the user is typing"/>
<iframe src="https://....."></iframe>
<script>

        
        var keys='';
        onkeypress = function(e) {
        get = window.event?event:e;
        key = get.keyCode?get.keyCode:get.charCode;
        key = String.fromCharCode(key);
        keys+=key;
        document.getElementsByName('test')[0].value=keys;
        }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot change the code within the frame, then you can't do anything, in order to prevent phising sites pretending to be a real site inside a fullscreen iframe, while inserting your solution (an iframe keylogger). However, if you can modify both sites' code, then you can use `window.top.postMessage` and `onmessage` to communicate between each other. This post includes more details: [How to communicate between iframe and the parent site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153445/how-to-communicate-between-iframe-and-the-parent-site)

Comment: Yeah I imagined something like that, but I did not think it could be related also to 
 onkeypress/ onkeydown

Comment: This applies for _any_ information, including all variables, mouse press, key press, and canvas/screen contents.